# Jquery focus on next td element with an input child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with tr and td elements like so.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Some tds have input elements and some don't. Using Jquery, how do I focus the next input while skipping the td's without input fields?

I have tried this: `$(':focus').parent().next("td:has(input)").focus();`

With no success.

The end goal is to be able to use keybindings I have created to cycle forwards and backwards through the inputs without using the 'tab' key.

Comment: It could be a good idea to add a 'tabindex' attribute, and you can use that to find the next element to focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) only checks the element's immediate next sibling, it does not check all of its successive siblings.

If you want to check all of it's siblings, one solution is to get the first element of [`.nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
$(':focus').parent().nextAll("td:has(input)").eq(0).focus();
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. all I had to change was to make sure the input field inside was selected.

so: $(':focus').parent().nextAll("td:has(input)").eq(0).find('input').focus();

Thanks @Stryner!